# Form goes up on keypad is open in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I used NestedScrollView with TabView and one of the tab contain Form.
Issue:  while open system keyboard on that for UI goes up

[image]
[image]

I want UI or Widgets should be on their place while keyboard is open.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered same problem, on adding a property of Scaffold in widget build method (resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false), attaching a code snippet below.
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
final themeNotifier = Provider.of(context);

return 
Scaffold( 
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, 
....// your other code

you can try this, it worked for me

Comment: I already added resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,